# How can I access the values in the .env config? using js-web

Tags: node.js

How can I access the values in the .env config? I'm using the js-web framework.

Can't find anything about it in the docs https://js-web-framework.com.

Comment: Its given [here](https://js-web-framework.com/docs/cli), how to get the .env file

Comment: Yes, I have the file but can I Access it from the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it by importing the config

```
import {
 htmlRoute,
 start,
 back,
 config // add config
} from 'js-web'

console.log(config) // will return you .env as object
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was needed